# Parse error: unexpected end of file

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to generate JavaScript Charts in PHP based on data in MYSQL
Not sure what is wrong with this code since all the tags are correctly placed.
Below is my code.
Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks

```
<?php

include("includes/fusioncharts.php");

$hostdb = "localhost";  // MySQl host
$userdb = "root";  // MySQL username
$passdb = "";  // MySQL password
$namedb = "fusioncharts_phpsample";  // MySQL database name

$dbhandle = new mysqli($hostdb, $userdb, $passdb, $namedb);

if ($dbhandle->connect_error) {
exit("There was an error with your connection: ".$dbhandle->connect_error);
}


$strQuery = "SELECT Name, Population FROM Country ORDER BY Population DESC LIMIT 10";


$result = $dbhandle->query($strQuery) or exit("Error code ({$dbhandle->errno}): {$dbhandle->error}");


if ($result) {

$arrData = array(
  "chart" => array
  (
    "caption" => "Top 10 Most Populous Countries",
    "paletteColors" => "#0075c2",
    "bgColor" => "#ffffff",
    "borderAlpha"=> "20",
    "canvasBorderAlpha"=> "0",
    "usePlotGradientColor"=> "0",
    "plotBorderAlpha"=> "10",
    "showXAxisLine"=> "1",
    "xAxisLineColor" => "#999999",
    "showValues" => "0",
    "divlineColor" => "#999999",
    "divLineIsDashed" => "1",
    "showAlternateHGridColor" => "0"
  )

);

$arrData["data"] = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
array_push($arrData["data"], array(
  "label" => $row["Name"],
  "value" => $row["Population"]
    )
  );
}

$jsonEncodedData = json_encode($arrData);

$columnChart = new FusionCharts("column2D", "myFirstChart" , 600, 300, "chart-1", "json", $jsonEncodedData);
$columnChart->render();
$dbhandle->close(); 

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the closing `}` to your `if ($result) {` line.

Answer (score 1):

`if ($result) {` condition does not end anywhere because`}` is missing.

Add `}` in your last line.